# How to add timestamp to file in script

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, timestamps

I'm a newby in making scripts and need help in making a

`timestamp` to the file `domoticz.db` so the output will be `$DEST_FOLDER/domoticz.timestamp.db`

in the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

DEST_FOLDER='/home/shares/public/usbdrive/Domoticz/'
BACKUP_CMD='/bin/cp'

$BACKUP_CMD /home/pi/domoticz/domoticz.db $DEST_FOLDER
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `$(date '+%Y%m%d')` to have a timestamp like 20210219

Comment: What file are you talking about? All I see is a couple of folders and a command.

Comment: I’m guessing you want something like `$DEST_FOLDER/domoticz.timestamp.db`.  This isn’t very clear from the question so I suggest you [edit] it to clarify.  It would also be useful to show what you’ve already tried and/or researched.  See [ask]

Comment: Please double-quote your variables when you use them. (For example, `"$DEST_FOLDER"` instead of the plain `$DEST_FOLDER`.) I'd also recommend that you use lower case variables for names rather than upper case ones. These two simple changes really will save you pain later on when you write more complex scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filename=domoticz.db
name="${filename%.*}"
extension="${filename##*.}"

timestamp=$(date "+%Y%m%d")

cp domoticz.db /the/folder/"${name}.${timestamp}.${extension}"
```

Output file:

```
/the/folder/domoticz.20190930.db
```